# How to set TabBarIcon color correctly in SwiftUI since .accentColor is deprecated?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

It seems quite hard to change the color of the selected `UITabBarItem` in SwiftUI. To define the design at central place in the app, I tried to use `.appearance()` to do this, but nothing worked:

```
// Only effects the unselected items
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .red

// No effect, deprecated in iOS 8(!)
UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = .cyan

// Only effects the title, not the icon 
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .normal)

// No effect
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

The only thing that works is to not use the appearance proxy but setting the color "manually" in the SwiftUI `View` definition using `.accentColor`

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
             SomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Main", systemImage: "list.dash")
                        .tint(.green) // No effect
                }
                .tint(.yellow) // No effect
        }
        .accentColor(.orange)
        
        // No effect
        //.tint(.red)
    }
}
```

However, `.accentColor` will also be deprecated:

> 'accentColor' will be deprecated in a future version of iOS: Use the
> assets catalog's accent color or View.tint(_:) instead

Using `.tint` on the `TabView` has no effect. `UITabBarItem` has no `tint` appearance property.

**To how to correctly set the icon color without using `accentColor` (preferably via the appearance)**

Comment: Did you try to put the tint on the tab items

Comment: Yes, this has no effect either. I have updated the example code in the question accordingly.